# No tag "link" defined in tag library imported with prefix "h"

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, tomcat

I'm using Eclipse Mars 1 and Tomcat 7, JDK 1.6.

I get this error despite having added jsf-api-2.2.9.jar and jsf-impl-2.2.9.jar in my WEB-INF/lib folder. I can't figure out what's wrong. Probably I have missed some obvious issue, since the problem seem to be that it can't find the tag definition for link.

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with
>   path [/foodbase] threw exception [/recipes_search.jsp (line: 108,
>   column: 20) No tag "link" defined in tag library imported with prefix
>   "h"] with root cause

On my recipes_print page I have the following defined in order to get the recepie that should be displayed.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
  pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="f" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="h" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
   <f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{recepieViewController.recipes}"
            converter="#{recepieConverter}" converterMessage="Bad request. Unknown user."
            required="true" requiredMessage="Bad request. Please use a link from within the system."
        />
    </f:metadata>
<head>

...
```

Here's how my JSP page look.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
  pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="f" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="h" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
...
<f:view>

<h:form binding="#{recepieController.form}" >

    <h:messages style="color:red;margin:8px;" />

<h:panelGrid columns="2">
  <h:outputText value="Title"></h:outputText>
  <h:inputText value="#{recepieController.searchTitle}" >
  </h:inputText>

  ...  

 </h:panelGrid>
    <h:commandButton action="#{recepieController.search}" value="Search"
    accesskey="s">
     </h:commandButton>

    </h:form>

 <h:form binding="#{recepieController.tableForm}" rendered="#{not empty recepieController.recipesList}">
        <h:dataTable value="#{recepieController.recipesList}" var="item" >

            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:column>
                        <h:outputText value="Title"></h:outputText>
                    </h:column>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{item.name}"></h:outputText>
            </h:column>
 ....
            <h:column>
                <h:link value="Details" outcome="recipes_print">
                    <f:param name="id" value="#{item}" />
                </h:link>
            </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>

    </h:form>
 </f:view>
```

Comment: The error message ends with "with root cause"--what comes after that?

Comment: Thanks nitind and BalusC. I was not aware of that JSP was not applicable for JSF 2.0 and onwards.